# I wanna resist id in serial number

Tags: python, django

I wanna resist id in serial number like 1,2,3・・・.I wrote codes to resist User data like,

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.
def get_next():
    try:
        return Users.objects.latest('pk').increment_num + 1
    except:
        return 1

class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=get_next, editable=False)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
```

But when I try to resist user's data,

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'1' is not a valid UUID."]

error happens.
So I rewrote `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=get_next)`, but if I resist multiple user's data, only id=1's data is remain and I cannot understand but other data was deleted. What is wrong in my code? How should I fix this?

Comment: UUID is not an integer, so you can't save an integer value to it. Why don't you let Django auto-generate the UUID for you? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield where you just set `default=uuid.uuid4`. Similarly if you want to use an integer field, just let Django auto-increment for you. Trying to generate the next ID yourself is not safe fro race conditions.

Comment: the usage of the word `resist` makes this question hard to understand. What do you mean by resist?

Comment: resist means to put data to database.So i want to put serial number like  1,2,3 in id's column of db.

Comment: "resist means to put data to database". No it doesn't. The word you want is *persist*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUID is not a number but you can generate a new UUID simple

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
def get_next():
    return uuid.uuid4()

class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=get_next, editable=False)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
```

By default Django will store Integer Primary keys. In order to do that you need to remove some of your code.

```
from django.db import models


class Users(models.Model):
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
```

Pending on you database backend it will be sequential.

Comment: thanks your answer.I tried your codes,but in id column 23ds5a9iew34mc8 was registed.I wanna resist integer like 1,2,3・・・.I think UUIDField causes this error but how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need uuid for this since its only an integer!
...otherwise replace your **id** field with this

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=get_next, editable=False, autoincrement)
```

Then do

```
>>>python manage.py makemigrations
>>>python manage.py migrate
```