# UUID field in fresh Postgresql DB failing ValidationError: ["'1' is not a valid UUID."]

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration, uuid

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on what this error may be coming from.  I have just moved to Postgresql from sqllite and at the same time changed my ID fields to `UUID`.  For most of the models it works however I have isolated a few which are causing the migration to fail.

The error is:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
>   django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'1' is not a valid UUID."]

As I said this is a new db and am not aware of any code that would create rows upon migration so not sure where the 1 would be coming from.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444648/i-wanna-resist-id-in-serial-number) appears quite similar however the asker is explicitly setting the integer and trying to pass it as a `UUID`

Model

```
import uuid

class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Trace

```
        Running migrations:
      Applying survey.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2363, in to_python
        return uuid.UUID(value)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/uuid.py", line 137, in __init__
        hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 15, in 
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
        fake_initial=fake_initial,
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
        state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
        state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
        field,
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 407, in add_field
        definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 152, in column_sql
        default_value = self.effective_default(field)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 224, in effective_default
        default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 936, in get_db_prep_save
        return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2354, in get_db_prep_value
        value = self.to_python(value)
      File "/Users/jd/.virtualenvs/projectrisk_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2368, in to_python
        params={'value': value},
    django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'1' is not a valid UUID."]
```

Comment: Do you have data in those tables? `1` could be the previous auto-incremented `int` id for a row. Try creating a separate `uuid` column (instead of renaming the `id`) and repeat the migration.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk, appreciate the response.  I have renamed it to uuid and yes you are correct the migration succeeds.  I can't work out why id is having a problem though - I am using `DROP DATABASE db_name` and then `CREATE DATABASE db_name OWNER owner_name` and then re-running the migrations and I still have the error when the field is named id.  I assume that somehow a row is being created on migrate and it is as an integer id?

Comment: For anyone else that googles here I have found some additional information, although still unresolved... [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg182117.html) and [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/206)

Comment: Adding `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to my apache config fix this issue for me.